# Where should I ask a question about fonts in Photoshop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Not sure if this is the right place, but I'm wanting to ask a question about how to achieve a certain font appearance in Photoshop. Should this be posted in [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Photo Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com) site covers Photoshop only in the context of photo manipulation, not general Photoshop questions.

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) does cover questions about font appearances.

Comment: If you can't wait, try superuser. It's a long shot, but someone may answer your question there.

Comment: The [Photoshop tag on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop?tab=Newest) currently has 1099 questions.